# Is there a RSS feed of articles added to my Wikipedia watchlist

Tags: rss, wikipedia

I would like to have an RSS feed with the articles I personally add to my Watchlist. So each time I star an article, the RSS feed gets updated with the article title, url, description. I could then add it to my RSS reader or any other service using IFTTT.

Seems like a pretty regular thing, but cannot find it anywhere online. Suggestions anyone?

Comment: I don't think anything like that exists. You would probably need to create a script the periodically checks the pages in your watchlist and creates an RSS feed of changes.

Answer (score 3):

You can syndicate your Wikipedia watch list using a 'token' as an Aton or RSS feed as described by [Wikipedia: Syndication](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aSyndication):

> 1. Go to Special:Preferences
> 2. Click the "Watchlist" tab
> 3. Make up a token, or copy and paste the "randomly-generated value" into the "Watchlist token" box
> 4. Click "Save"
>
> Your watchlist Atom feed can be found at http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=feedwatchlist&wlowner=USERNAME&wltoken=TOKEN&feedformat=atom, where USERNAME is your username without the User: prefix and TOKEN is the watchlist token you saved in your preferences. If you would prefer an RSS feed rather than an Atom one, use "feedformat=rss" in place of "feedformat=atom".

Comment: thanks.. I knew that one already, that is not exactly what I want. I want the "Starring" of articles to be captured by the Watchlist. Which it doesn't - only changes to the articles. Just like starring or favouriting presentations on Slideshare, videos on YouTube, etc.

Comment: @ThiemeHennis oh I understand now- I'll do some poking around...